# Fill a div with a reponsive <img> and position centrally

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

How can I ensure that the `img` within the container is centered and scaling correctly from mobile to desktop? Here is a [demo on Codepen](http://codepen.io/ssosina/pen/pbepeo). Scale to mobile to better understand the problem

**HTML**

```
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/470/310/people" alt="" /> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image-container{
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
 max-height: 500px;
 background: red;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 }

 img{
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: -50%;
 left: 0;
}
```

I ask this because the image loses it height on mobile and looks incorrect. I sort of what this to work like `background-size: cover. I'd like the image to completely fill the container

Answer (score 0):

To center image horizontally and vertically inside div you can set `top: 50%` and `left: 50%` and then just add `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`.

To make image responsive you can use `max-width: 100%` and by default height is auto.

```css
.image-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/470/310/people" alt="" />
</div>
```

Other option is to use `Flexbox` if you don't want to use `relative/absolute` position but to keep img responsive you can use `object-fit: contain` with `height: 100%`

```css
.image-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/470/310/people" alt="" />
</div>
```

If you want `img` to behave like `background-size: cover` one way to that is to use `object-fit: cover` with `height: 100%` and `width: 100%`

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.image-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/470/310/people" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: To be honest i'm fairly new to flexbox. I used your code within my Bourbon grid and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `margin:0 auto;` to align center horizontally. `Remove width:100%` as this will stretch width of an image unless you want it to. Keep `height:auto` to adjust with `width`.

```css
.image-container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

img{
 height: auto;
 max-width: 100%;
 margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/470/310/people" alt="" />
</div>
```